# PyYAML load version number float (with trailing zero) as string

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

example.yaml

```yaml
version: 0.20
```

main.py

```
import yaml

with open("example.yaml", "r") as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Actual output:

```
{'version': 0.2}
```

Desired output:

```
{'version': '0.20'}
```

Looks like yaml is parsing the `version` field as a float, and hence removes the 0 at the end. Using Python, how do I prevent the version field from converting to a float value?

---

The are two workarounds that modify the YAML to express the `version` field as a string:

example.yaml

```yaml
version: '0.20'
```

```yaml
version: 0.20.0
```

But I want to handle this inside Python.

Answer (score 0):

#### Load all floating point values that end with `"0"` as strings

One possible hack:

```py
class Loader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    def construct_yaml_float(self, node):
        # CUSTOM HACK: returns unchanged string if ends with "0".
        if node.value.endswith("0"):
            return node.value

        # UNCHANGED, ORIGINAL CODE:
        value = self.construct_scalar(node)
        value = value.replace('_', '').lower()
        sign = +1
        if value[0] == '-':
            sign = -1
        if value[0] in '+-':
            value = value[1:]
        if value == '.inf':
            return sign*self.inf_value
        elif value == '.nan':
            return self.nan_value
        elif ':' in value:
            digits = [float(part) for part in value.split(':')]
            digits.reverse()
            base = 1
            value = 0.0
            for digit in digits:
                value += digit*base
                base *= 60
            return sign*value
        else:
            return sign*float(value)
            
Loader.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:float', Loader.construct_yaml_float)
```

Then:

```py
>>> yaml.load("version: 0.20", Loader=Loader)
{'version': '0.20'}
```

Notes:

- Consider also converting all float `"version"` values to string `str(data["version"])` so that `0.1 -> "0.1"`.
- This also converts everything that is not the key `"version"`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom loader for `"version"` keys

Load the corresponding value for a `"version"` key using the original, unparsed string.

```py
import collections

import yaml
from yaml import MappingNode
from yaml.constructor import ConstructorError


class Loader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
        if not isinstance(node, MappingNode):
            raise ConstructorError(None, None,
                    "expected a mapping node, but found %s" % node.id,
                    node.start_mark)
        mapping = {}
        for key_node, value_node in node.value:
            key = self.construct_object(key_node, deep=deep)
            if not isinstance(key, collections.abc.Hashable):
                raise ConstructorError("while constructing a mapping", node.start_mark,
                        "found unhashable key", key_node.start_mark)
            # CUSTOM VERSION KEY HANDLING:
            if key == "version":
                value = value_node.value
            else:
                value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
            mapping[key] = value
        return mapping
```

Then:

```py
>>> document = "version: 0.20\nsome_number: 0.20"
>>> yaml.load(document, Loader=Loader)
{'version': '0.20', 'some_number': 0.2}
```

Notes:

- This replaces *all* instances of `"version"` keys. If only the root level is desired, you may wish to fiddle around to ensure only depth=0 `"version"` nodes are handled this way.

Comment: This is doesn't seem working.. Can you try having a example.yaml with version: 0.20 in it ? rather than having a document as string directly.

Comment: @BhanuKiran Works for me with `PyYAML==6.0`. See minimal example: https://github.com/YodaEmbedding/experiments/tree/master/py/so/yaml_parsing